# web scrapping Proplem list object has no attribute timeout

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, alfresco-webscripts, ironwebscraper

I am trying to do web scrapping using Selenium, I want to download images from Google but I have more than one issue:

1. I got this issue `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'timeout'`.
2. I can't deal with base64 image and can't download it.
3. I have an issue with the function  name download_image in my code.
4. also there are URLs contain image ural ,how to download it
   anyone can help me

here is my Code :

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from selenium import webdriver
import time as t
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time as t
import urllib
import base64
try:
    os.mkdir("G:/Smokking_Project")    
except:
    pass

name="smoked"

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])
#driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe',options=chrome_options)  
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)  
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

strr="https://www.google.com/search?q=smokinng&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwi8k9zn9eOBAxVtlycCHTa_DnUQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=smokinng&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIJCAAQGBCABBAKMgkIABAYEIAEEAoyCQgAEBgQgAQQCjoECCMQJzoFCAAQgAQ6BggAEAUQHjoECAAQHjoICAAQgAQQsQM6BAgAEAM6BwgAEBgQgARQjwdY8xJg-RloAHAAeACAAb0BiAHsCZIBAzAuOZgBAKABAaoBC2d3cy13aXotaW1nwAEB&sclient=img&ei=uUwhZfzSFO2unsEPtv66qAc&bih=723&biw=1517&hl=en"

driver.get(strr)
t.sleep(3)
links=[]
x=1
last_height=0

def download_image(url,filename):
        resource = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        output = open(filename,"wb")
        output.write(resource.read())
        output.close()
    
while True:
     driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
     t.sleep(4)    
     #try:
     img_link = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,'//a[1]/div[1]/img')))
     t.sleep(1)

     for img in img_link:
        url = img.get_attribute('src')
        if url not in links:
            links.append(url)
            print (url)
            
            try:
                os.mkdir('G://Smokking_Project//'+name)
            except:
                pass
            try:
                os.mkdir('G://Smokking_Project//'+name)
            except:
                pass
            file_name='Smokking_Project//'+name+'//'+str(x)+'.jpg'
            download_image(img_link,file_name)
            
            x+=1
        #except:
            #print('-',end='')
     new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
     print(new_height)
     if new_height == last_height:
        break
     last_height = new_height
            
driver.close()`
```

below is full error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\Geka\Desktop\openCV\vision_ahmed_ibrahim\webscrapping\webscrapping_Google.ipynb Cell 6 line 6
     62         pass
     63     file_name='Smokking_Project//'+name+'//'+str(x)+'.jpg'
---> 64     download_image(img_link,file_name)
     66     x+=1
     67 #except:
     68     #print('-',end='')

c:\Users\Geka\Desktop\openCV\vision_ahmed_ibrahim\webscrapping\webscrapping_Google.ipynb Cell 6 line 3
     33 def download_image(url,filename):
---> 34         resource = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
     35         output = open(filename,"wb")
     36         output.write(resource.read())

File c:\Users\Geka\anaconda3\Lib\urllib\request.py:216, in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    214 else:
    215     opener = _opener
--> 216 return opener.open(url, data, timeout)

File c:\Users\Geka\anaconda3\Lib\urllib\request.py:509, in OpenerDirector.open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    506     if data is not None:
    507         req.data = data
--> 509 req.timeout = timeout
    510 protocol = req.type
    512 # pre-process request

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'timeout'
```

Comment: You have multiple questions, you should post each issue you're having a single question.

Comment: i got this error 'list' object has no attribute 'timeout'.

Comment: Can we see the full traceback? Right now, it's hard to tell where that error could be coming from.

Comment: @TheTridentGuysupportsUkraine i edited the main question body  and  raised the full error

Comment: I think you meant to pass `url`, not `img_link`, as the first arg to `download_image()`.

Comment: And this is a good example of why choosing meaningful variable names matters.  If that variable had a name that better described what it actually was, like maybe `list_of_imgs`, or even just `imgs`, it would have been more noticeable as an inappropriate argument in the function call to `download_image()`.  But as it was, `img_link` _seemed_ like an appropriate variable to pass to that function, when it actually wasn't.

Comment: @JohnGordon you are right it working but it downloads only 24 images and gets the same error  raised above, how can I make it continue downloading not only for 24 images  (AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'timeout')

Comment: Looks like your loop found an `<img>` element that did not have a `src` attribute, so `url` got a value of `None`.  You should probably add some code in your loop to skip such images without downloading them.

Comment: @JohnGordon could you help me in this please

Comment: I already told you what to do.  If `url` is blank/null, skip it and go on to the next image link.  What more help do you need?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255557/discussion-between-ahmed-gaber-and-john-gordon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errors we have Identified in your code are

1)AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'timeout': This error occurs because you're passing a list of elements (img_link) to the download_image function instead of a single URL string. You need to pass the url variable to the function instead.

2)Handling Base64 images: To handle Base64 images, you need to decode the Base64 string and save it as an image file.

3)Downloading URLs that contain image URLs: You can download images from URLs by sending an HTTP request to the URL and saving the response content.

Let's modify your code to address these issues:

```
import os
import time
import urllib.request
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

try:
    os.mkdir("G:/Smokking_Project")
except FileExistsError:
    pass

name = "smoked"

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

strr = "https://www.google.com/search?q=smokinng&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwi8k9zn9eOBAxVtlycCHTa_DnUQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=smokinng&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIJCAAQGBCABBAKMgkIABAYEIAEEAoyCQgAEBgQgAQQCjoECCMQJzoFCAAQgAQ6BggAEAUQHjoECAAQHjoICAAQgAQQsQM6BAgAEAM6BwgAEBgQgARQjwdY8xJg-RloAHAAeACAAb0BiAHsCZIBAzAuOZgBAKABAaoBC2d3cy13aXotaW1nwAEB&sclient=img&ei=uUwhZfzSFO2unsEPtv66qAc&bih=723&biw=1517&hl=en"

driver.get(strr)
time.sleep(3)

x = 1
last_height = 0

def download_image(url, filename):
    resource = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    output = open(filename, "wb")
    output.write(resource.read())
    output.close()

while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(4)
    
    img_links = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//a[1]/div[1]/img')))
    time.sleep(1)

    for img in img_links:
        url = img.get_attribute('src')
        if url:
            if url.startswith('data:image'):
                # Decode Base64 image and save it
                img_data = url.split(',')[1]
                img_data = img_data.encode()
                filename = f'G:/Smokking_Project/{name}/{x}.jpg'
                with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
                    f.write(base64.b64decode(img_data))
            else:
                # Download image from URL
                try:
                    os.makedirs(f'G:/Smokking_Project/{name}', exist_ok=True)
                except FileExistsError:
                    pass
                filename = f'G:/Smokking_Project/{name}/{x}.jpg'
                download_image(url, filename)
            x += 1
    
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    print(new_height)
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height

driver.close()
```

This code should address the issues you mentioned. It handles Base64 images by decoding them and saves them as image files. Additionally, it downloads images from URLs by sending an HTTP request and saving the response content.